# Анимация исчезновения и появления стрелок в SVG

Tags: css, html5, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

У меня есть SVG, который состоит из 5 стрелок. Я хочу сделать последовательное исчезновение  каждой стрелки, снизу вверх для каждой стрелки.

Я хочу, чтобы первая стрелка исчезла, затем вторая и т.д. И когда верхняя стрелка исчезнет,  снова запустить анимацию постепенного исчезновения для  каждой стрелки.

Здесь мой код на [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gyJZEy)

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="80" height="80" viewBox="0 0 122.91 110.38">
    <defs>
        <style>.hg{fill:#ee2330;opacity:0}</style>
    </defs>
    <g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2">
        <g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1">
            <rect>
                <animate id="hg0" begin="0;hg0.end" dur="8s"
                attributeName="visibility" from="hide" to="hide"/>
            </rect>
            <path class="hg" d="M61.65 86.78l-.16-.06L0 109.38v.99l61.49-22.65 61.43 22.66v-.99L61.65 86.78z">
                <animate id="hg1" attributeName="opacity" values="0;1;0" dur="4s" begin="hg0.begin;hg0.end" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
            </path>
            <path class="hg" d="M0 87.69v1.49l61.49-22.66 61.43 22.67v-1.48L61.49 65.04 0 87.69z">
                <animate id="hg2" attributeName="opacity" values="0;1;0" dur="4s" begin="hg0.begin+1s;hg0.end+1s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
            </path>
            <path class="hg" d="M0 66.05v1.97l61.49-22.66 61.43 22.67v-1.97L61.49 43.39 0 66.05z">
                <animate id="hg3" attributeName="opacity" values="0;1;0" dur="4s" begin="hg0.begin+2s;hg0.end+2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
            </path>
            <path class="hg" d="M61.49 21.65L0 44.31v2.64l61.49-22.66 61.43 22.67v-2.64l-61-22.51-.43-.16z">
                <animate id="hg4" attributeName="opacity" values="0;1;0" dur="4s" begin="hg0.begin+3s;hg0.end+3s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
            </path>
            <path class="hg" d="M0 22.66v3.13L61.49 3.13l61.43 22.67v-3.13L61.49 0 0 22.66z">
                <animate id="hg5" attributeName="opacity" values="0;1;0" dur="4s" begin="hg0.begin+4s;hg0.end+4s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
            </path>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [SVG Fade in Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55929953/7394871) от участника  [@Pedro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3646445/pedro).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/55929953/7394871

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вариант с `css` `@keyframes` и `animation-delay`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="80" height="80" viewBox="0 0 122.91 110.38">
  <style>
    path {
      fill: red; opacity: 0;
      animation: 5.5s opacity infinite;
    }
    @keyframes opacity {
      15% {opacity: 0} 
      35% {opacity: 1}
      65% {opacity: 1} 
      85% {opacity: 0}
    }
    #hg2 {animation-delay: 0.5s}
    #hg3 {animation-delay: 1.0s}
    #hg4 {animation-delay: 1.5s}
    #hg5 {animation-delay: 2.0s}
  </style>
  <path id="hg1" d="M61.65 86.78l-.16-.06L0 109.38v.99l61.49-22.65 61.43 22.66v-.99L61.65 86.78z"></path>
  <path id="hg2" d="M0 87.69v1.49l61.49-22.66 61.43 22.67v-1.48L61.49 65.04 0 87.69z"></path>
  <path id="hg3" d="M0 66.05v1.97l61.49-22.66 61.43 22.67v-1.97L61.49 43.39 0 66.05z"></path>
  <path id="hg4" d="M61.49 21.65L0 44.31v2.64l61.49-22.66 61.43 22.67v-2.64l-61-22.51-.43-.16z"></path>
  <path id="hg5" d="M0 22.66v3.13L61.49 3.13l61.43 22.67v-3.13L61.49 0 0 22.66z"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Есть сбой в длительности появления, исчезновения, - в частности, пока верхняя галочка исчезает уже успевают появляться две нижние галочки.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT согласен, надо посчитать задержку получше

Answer (score 5):

Ещё два примера использования задержек  с помощью `keyTimes` в `SVG`, и в `css animation-delay`.

### SVG Loader

Принцип работы абсолютно такой же как в первом примере

```html
<svg width="200px"  height="200px"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" class="lds-ellipsis" style="background: none;">

<circle cx="84" cy="50" r="0" fill="#413fa4">
 <animate attributeName="r" 
          values="10;0;0;0;0" 
          keyTimes="0;0.25;0.5;0.75;1" 
          keySplines="0 0.5 0.5 1;0 0.5 0.5 1;0 0.5 0.5 1;0 0.5 0.5 1" 
          calcMode="spline" 
          dur="2.8s" 
          repeatCount="indefinite" 
          begin="0s"></animate>
<animate attributeName="cx" 
         values="84;84;84;84;84" 
         keyTimes="0;0.25;0.5;0.75;1" 
         keySplines="0 0.5 0.5 1;0 0.5 0.5 1;0 0.5 0.5 1;0 0.5 0.5 1" 
         calcMode="spline" 
         dur="2.8s" 
         repeatCount="indefinite" 
         begin="0s"></animate>
</circle>
<circle cx="46.4254" cy="50" r="10" fill="#22b75b">
<animate attributeName="r" 
         values="0;10;10;10;0" 
         keyTimes="0;0.25;0.5;0.75;1" 
         keySplines="0 0.5 0.5 1;0 0.5 0.5 1;0 0.5 0.5 1;0 0.5 0.5 1" 
         calcMode="spline" 
         dur="2.8s" 
         repeatCount="indefinite" 
         begin="-1.4s"></animate>
<animate attributeName="cx" 
         values="16;16;50;84;84" 
         keyTimes="0;0.25;0.5;0.75;1" 
         keySplines="0 0.5 0.5 1;0 0.5 0.5 1;0 0.5 0.5 1;0 0.5 0.5 1" 
         calcMode="spline" 
         dur="2.8s" 
         repeatCount="indefinite" 
         begin="-1.4s"></animate>
</circle>
<circle cx="16" cy="50" r="8.94865" fill="#413fa4">
<animate attributeName="r" 
         values="0;10;10;10;0" 
         keyTimes="0;0.25;0.5;0.75;1" 
         keySplines="0 0.5 0.5 1;0 0.5 0.5 1;0 0.5 0.5 1;0 0.5 0.5 1" 
         calcMode="spline" 
         dur="2.8s" 
         repeatCount="indefinite" 
         begin="-0.7s"></animate>
<animate attributeName="cx" 
         values="16;16;50;84;84" 
         keyTimes="0;0.25;0.5;0.75;1" 
         keySplines="0 0.5 0.5 1;0 0.5 0.5 1;0 0.5 0.5 1;0 0.5 0.5 1"   calcMode="spline" 
         dur="2.8s" 
         repeatCount="indefinite" 
         begin="-0.7s"></animate>
         </circle>
<circle cx="84" cy="50" r="1.05135" fill="#22b75b">
<animate attributeName="r" 
         values="0;10;10;10;0" 
         keyTimes="0;0.25;0.5;0.75;1" 
         keySplines="0 0.5 0.5 1;0 0.5 0.5 1;0 0.5 0.5 1;0 0.5 0.5 1" 
         calcMode="spline" 
         dur="2.8s" 
         repeatCount="indefinite" 
         begin="0s"></animate>
<animate attributeName="cx" 
         values="16;16;50;84;84" 
         keyTimes="0;0.25;0.5;0.75;1" 
         keySplines="0 0.5 0.5 1;0 0.5 0.5 1;0 0.5 0.5 1;0 0.5 0.5 1"   calcMode="spline" 
         dur="2.8s" 
         repeatCount="indefinite" 
         begin="0s"></animate></circle>
<circle cx="80.4254" cy="50" r="10" fill="#413fa4">
<animate attributeName="r" 
         values="0;0;10;10;10" 
         keyTimes="0;0.25;0.5;0.75;1" 
         keySplines="0 0.5 0.5 1;0 0.5 0.5 1;0 0.5 0.5 1;0 0.5 0.5 1"   calcMode="spline" 
         dur="2.8s" 
         repeatCount="indefinite" 
         begin="0s"></animate>
<animate attributeName="cx" 
         values="16;16;16;50;84" 
         keyTimes="0;0.25;0.5;0.75;1" 
         keySplines="0 0.5 0.5 1;0 0.5 0.5 1;0 0.5 0.5 1;0 0.5 0.5 1" 
         calcMode="spline" 
         dur="2.8s" 
         repeatCount="indefinite" 
         begin="0s"></animate>
         </circle>
</svg>
```

### CSS Loader

```css
body {
  background-color: #1d1f20;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-content: space-around;
}

.sk-wave {
  width: 240px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.sk-wave .sk-circle {
  background-color: #337ab7;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius:50%;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation: sk-wave-stretch-delay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
          animation: sk-wave-stretch-delay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.sk-wave .sk-circle-1 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.2s;
          animation-delay: -1.2s;
}

.sk-wave .sk-circle-2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.1s;
          animation-delay: -1.1s;
}

.sk-wave .sk-circle-3 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1s;
          animation-delay: -1s;
}

.sk-wave .sk-circle-4 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.9s;
          animation-delay: -0.9s;
}

.sk-wave .sk-circle-5 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.8s;
          animation-delay: -0.8s;
}

.sk-wave .sk-circle-6 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.7s;
          animation-delay: -0.7s;
}

.sk-wave .sk-circle-7 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.6s;
          animation-delay: -0.6s;
}

.sk-wave .sk-circle-8 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.5s;
          animation-delay: -0.5s;
}

.sk-wave .sk-circle-9 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.4s;
          animation-delay: -0.4s;
}

.sk-wave .sk-circle-10 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.3s;
          animation-delay: -0.3s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sk-wave-stretch-delay {
  0%, 40%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.4);
            transform: scale(0.4);
   opacity: 0.4; 
  }

  20% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
   opacity: 1; 
  }
}

@keyframes sk-wave-stretch-delay {
  0%, 40%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.4);
            transform: scale(0.4);
   opacity: 0.4;
  }

  20% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
   opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='sk-wave'>
    <div class='sk-circle sk-circle-1'></div>
    <div class='sk-circle sk-circle-2'></div>
    <div class='sk-circle sk-circle-3'></div>
    <div class='sk-circle sk-circle-4'></div>
    <div class='sk-circle sk-circle-5'></div>
    <div class='sk-circle sk-circle-6'></div>
    <div class='sk-circle sk-circle-7'></div>
    <div class='sk-circle sk-circle-8'></div>
    <div class='sk-circle sk-circle-9'></div>
    <div class='sk-circle sk-circle-10'></div>
  </div>
```

Источник ответа: @Alexandr_TT

Comment: у [Странника](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/976958/330688) конечно меньше кода ...на много ..:))

Answer (score 4):

Самое простое решение - использовать атрибут `keyTimes` для управления временем появления и исчезновения.
У нас есть пять стрелок. Анимация первой из них занимает одну секунду, чтобы появиться, затем ждет, пока другие четыре исчезнут. Затем требуется одна секунда, чтобы исчезнуть снова, и ждет, пока остальные четыре сделают то же самое.

Это означает, что анимация занимает всего 10 секунд для каждой стрелки. И в этой анимации пять ключевых моментов:

- при 0сек. значение непрозрачности равно `0`
- при 1сек., значение непрозрачности равно `1`
- при 5сек., значение непрозрачности равно `1`
- при 6сек., значение непрозрачности равно `0`
- при 10сек., значение непрозрачности равно `0`

Атрибут `keyTimes работает` в сочетании с атрибутом `values`.
Он указывает, в какое время в анимации непрозрачность должна быть при каждом значении.

**Таким образом, он должен иметь то же количество значений, что и в атрибуте `values`.**

Еще одна вещь, которую вы должны знать о значениях `keyTimes`, это то, что значения времени должны быть в долях от длительности.

Когда во второй раз анимация больше (1s ), мы должны использовать 0,1 (1s 10s).
Таким образом, наш атрибут `values` должен быть "0; 1; 1; 0; 0", а наш атрибут `keyTimes` будет "0; 0,1; 0,5; 0,6; 1".

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="80" height="80" viewBox="0 0 122.91 110.38">
    <defs>
        <style>.hg{fill:#ee2330;opacity:0}</style>
    </defs>
    <g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2">
        <g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1">
            <path class="hg" d="M61.65 86.78l-.16-.06L0 109.38v.99l61.49-22.65 61.43 22.66v-.99L61.65 86.78z">
                <animate attributeName="opacity" dur="10s" keyTimes="0;0.1;0.5;0.6;1" values="0;1;1;0;0" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
            </path>
            <path class="hg" d="M0 87.69v1.49l61.49-22.66 61.43 22.67v-1.48L61.49 65.04 0 87.69z">
                <animate attributeName="opacity" dur="10s" keyTimes="0;0.1;0.5;0.6;1" values="0;1;1;0;0" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="1s"/>
            </path>
            <path class="hg" d="M0 66.05v1.97l61.49-22.66 61.43 22.67v-1.97L61.49 43.39 0 66.05z">
                <animate attributeName="opacity" dur="10s" keyTimes="0;0.1;0.5;0.6;1" values="0;1;1;0;0" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="2s"/>
            </path>
            <path class="hg" d="M61.49 21.65L0 44.31v2.64l61.49-22.66 61.43 22.67v-2.64l-61-22.51-.43-.16z">
                <animate attributeName="opacity" dur="10s" keyTimes="0;0.1;0.5;0.6;1" values="0;1;1;0;0" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="3s"/>
            </path>
            <path class="hg" d="M0 22.66v3.13L61.49 3.13l61.43 22.67v-3.13L61.49 0 0 22.66z">
                <animate attributeName="opacity" dur="10s" keyTimes="0;0.1;0.5;0.6;1" values="0;1;1;0;0" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="4s"/>
            </path>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55932266/7394871) от участника  [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).</sub>

Comment: @MaximLensky перевел топик с использованием `keyTimes` вроде тебя заинтересовала эта тема. Можно на примерах здесь ещё потренироваться

Comment: Опять не пришло уведомление или просто меня не было здесь по этому, на Тостер можно вызвать пользователя даже если его нету в вопросе/комментарии вот ещё ruSO эту плюшку вкрутила бы ..

Comment: @MaximLensky бывает, что не доходят сообщения. Но в основном доходят, если даже и не было меня на сайте  несколько дней

Comment: Саша ты щас здесь ?

Comment: @MaximLensky уже здесь